# How to send response inside then() method that is followed by another then() method?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
exports.confirm_new_app = (req, res) => {

    //get the app
    AppReq.findOne({_id: req.body.appId})
    .then( (app) => {
        if (app) {
            //remove additional info(reqDate,reqUserId)
            app = app.toObject()
            delete app.reqDate
            delete app.reqUserId
            //add it to apps collection
            let newApp = new App(app)
            return newApp.save()
        } else {
            //how to send this response??????
            res.status(404).json({
                message: "No application with the provided app Id!"
            })
        }
    })
    .then( (savedApp) => {
        //remove the savedApp from appReq collection
        return AppReq.remove({_id: savedApp._id})
    }).then( (removedApp) => {
        res.status(200).json(removedApp)
    })
    .catch( (err) => {
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        })
    })
}
```

what is the proper way of sending `res.status(404).json({...})` in the example above?
The current code will trigger an error because it attempts to send response twice!!

Comment: Could throw an error in your then(), which should cause the rest of the thens to be skipped, and do all res calls in the catch(). Would just need to look at err and decide if you need to do a 404 or a 500

Comment: Rather than a direct chain, you can branch.  So, put the next `.then()` handler on the `newApp.save()` as `return newApp.save().then(...)` and continue the flow from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw an error any time you have an error and want to exit the `.then()` chain. Then handle the errors in your catch.

So instead of

```
    else {
        //how to send this response??????
        res.status(404).json({
            message: "No application with the provided app Id!"
        })
    }
```

try:

```
    else {
        throw new Error('appId');
    }
```

then in your catch:

```
.catch( (err) => {
    if (err.message === 'appId') {
        res.status(404).json({
            message: "No application with the provided app Id!"
        })
    } else {
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        })
    }
})
```